# Changing Privacy settings when posting using the Facebook Sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I attempt to post something to Facebook through the SDK I cant seem to change the privacy settings, specifically who sees the post and who doesn't. Essentially it keeps posting to facebook but only I am allowed to see it. I want to change it so that everyone i am friends with can see it.

```
        this.postFacebook = function(){
          var privacy = {
            'value': 'CUSTOM',
            'friends': 'EVERYONE'
          };
              FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { name: 'asdf', link: 'www.google.com', caption:'tester', description: 'description', privacy: privacy});
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check the default privacy value for your app under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications – if that is set to “only me”, then you need to chose a broader setting there first. When posting via API, you can only restrict the privacy level the user has set for the app more, you can not specify a privacy level “broader” than that.

Comment: There is a way to know the app's privacy setted from the users?